# AlertController with textfields not moving up on iphone when testing

Tags: swift, swift3

My alertcontroller with textfields isn't moving up when I touch a textfield on my iphone5(10.2) but when testing on any simulator it works fine. I'm fairly new to this and have no idea why. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240540/uialertview-with-text-fields-not-moving-up) but don't fully understand how to implement the solution. Any insights would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController`?